# Jquery code doesn't run in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This code doesn't run in IE  but runs in google chrome.

**My code**

```
$('iframe[height="350px"]').attr('src',_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Reports/tt.rdl");
```

Comment: Which version on jQuery you are using? Which version of IE you are using?

Comment: IE 11 and jquery 1.9

Comment: How have you imported the jQuery to your page? Could you edit to the original question?

Comment: It going to be difficult to pin-point the problem with such limited information.  Could you please elaborate on more of the details?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Also, what emulation mode is IE in when viewing your page? (right click on page->inspect element->Emulation tab).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a IE issue. My experience with iframes is that you can't do anything with them in IE. Changing the src dynamically is hazardous to IE's health. We switched an entire company to Chrome due to IE limitations with iframes. I vaguely remember this was one of those issues.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707032/internet-explorer-how-to-change-iframes-src

Terrible...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML height *attribute* doesn't take units (unlike the CSS height property).

So try it without the "px".